# ExtJS opening new windows as tiled

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using ExtJS and have a desktop-like application running. One thing that is bugging me is when a new window is opened (bound within the center region of a viewport) it always opens in the top left of the viewport.

If multiple windows are opened, I want them to tile so they dont just sit ontop of one another...

any ideas?

(My initial thought was to cycle throught the windows in the `WindowMgr` and check if there is currently one at 0,0. If yes, check 100,100 etc until one is free.)

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do pretty much as you already describe:

```
Ext.Window.prototype._autoTile = function() {
    var x = 10,
        y = 10;

    Ext.WindowMgr.each(function( win ) {
        if ( win === this )  return;

        var pos = win.getPosition();

        if ( pos[0] > (x - 15)
            && pos[0] < (x + 15)
            && pos[1] > (y - 15)
            && pos[1] < (y + 15)
        ) {
            x += 15;
            y += 15;
        }
    }, this);

    this.setPagePosition(x, y);
};

Ext.Window.prototype.initComponent =
    Ext.Window.prototype.initComponent.createSequence(function() {
        if ( this.autoTile ) {
            this.on('show', this._autoTile, this, {single: true});
        }
    });

var win = new Ext.Window({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    autoTile: true
});

win.show();
```

This implementation was adequate for my needs but could stand to be made more complex with such things as checks for whether the repositioned window is breaking out of the viewport boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like how its added as an attribute to the component, great work!

Comment: Love the approach, but is this working on ExtJS4? I'm getting an 'unrecognized createSequence' error.

Comment: This was written for ExtJS 3. One of v4's many changes was removal of methods added to global objects, such as the createSequence method added to Function. That much can be replaced with calling Ext.Function.createSequence, but there is no guarantee that the rest will work.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in to do this so I think the approach you outlined above is quite reasonable. Also keep in mind you may need to deal with hidden/minimized/maximized windows depending on what your application allows.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated there is no built-in functionality to support this.

There is an [old discussion thread on the ExtJS forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?53390-auto-arranging-Ext.Window-panels-%28tiled-horizontal-vertical%29) about this, its for version 2.x however, but perhaps you can pickup some ideas for your implementation there.